# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: java, hibernate

The below hql query doesnot seem to find the specified constructor. The path and no of varable match.

```
List<ServiceRuleVO> serviceRules = session.createQuery("select new com.xxx.modules.service.valueobject.ServiceRuleVO(id, serviceTypeId,  "
    + "petLocationId,  startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime, status, recurFrequency, recurCount,  recurInterval, "
    + " recurByDays, recurByMonths,  recurByMonthDay,  billable, payable, modifiedBy,  modifiedTime) from ServiceRule where   "
    + "(startDate<=:toDate and (endDate>=:fromDate or endDate=:neverEndDate)) "
    + "or (id in (select distinct serviceRuleId from ServiceException where "
    + "(startDate>=:fromDateIntSE and startDate<=:toDateIntSE) or "
    + "(startDate<:fromDateIntSE1 and endDate between :fromDateIntSE2 and :toDateIntSE2)))")
.setParameter("toDate", toDate)
.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate)
.setParameter("neverEndDate", neverEndDate)
.setParameter("fromDateIntSE", fromDateInt)
.setParameter("toDateIntSE", toDateInt)
.setParameter("fromDateIntSE1", fromDateInt)
.setParameter("fromDateIntSE2", fromDateInt)
.setParameter("toDateIntSE2", toDateInt)
.list();
```

The ServiceRuleVO  constructor is

```
public ServiceRuleVO(int id, int serviceTypeId, int petLocationId,
Date startDate, Time startTime,  Date endDate, Time endTime,  int status, String recurFrequency,
    int recurCount, int recurInterval, String recurByDays,
    String recurByMonths, int recurByMonthDay, int billable, int payable,
    int modifiedBy, int modifiedTime) { ... }
```

It works if the time variables starttime and end time is removed from the sql and the constructor.

Any help..PLease..

Comment: Seems there is mismatch between the DB datatype and your Entity data type. You could recheck. If you want timestamp in data you could use java.util.Date with @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) in the entity. Do you have any particular reason to use java.sql.Time ?

Comment: in my database, ServiceRule table has startTime and endTime (datatype TIme) and startDate and endDate of datatype Date.. I am using java.sql.TIme as I want to save tonly the time parameters in startTime and endTime and only date parameters in startDate and endDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only time for example 09:56:20,

You could use java.util.Date, and use TemporalType.TIME as below

```
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "START_TIME")
public Date getStartTime () {
    return startTime;
}



@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "END_TIME")
public Date getEndTime () {
    return endTime;
}
```